# The meanings of 神経

Tags: meaning

I just came across the phrase

> どういう神経だ！
> What a nerve! (my translation)

in a book translated from English to Japanese. Because it's a translation I'm a little doubtful about whether it's correct/idiomatic.

I can think of three meanings of nerve in English:

1. The biological thingy;
2. The courage to do something;
3. The audacity to do something.

The context of the book means that meaning 3) must be intended. Yet when I look in [weblio](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E7%A5%9E%E7%B5%8C) and [kotobank](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E7%A5%9E%E7%B5%8C-81577#E7.B2.BE.E9.81.B8.E7.89.88.20.E6.97.A5.E6.9C.AC.E5.9B.BD.E8.AA.9E.E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E5.85.B8) I see nothing that looks like either meaning 2) or 3).

To what extent does 神経 mirror the English meanings?

Comment: "What a nerve!" does not make sense in English.

Comment: @istrasci As a life-long native English speaker of over 40 years, your comment puzzles me greatly.

Comment: @user3856370 You don't think "what nerve?" sounds right for the "audacity" meaning? It would sound weird with the "a" for that meaning. I guess a neurologist might say "what a nerve!" if they were impressed with a physical nerve, but that is a pretty specific scenario to imagine.

Comment: Googling it, I guess it exists. Still sounds very strange to me.

Comment: @Leebo Not quite. I think "What a nerve!" stands alone as a perfectly valid exclamation of outrage. I think "what nerve" is fine, but it sounds like an incomplete statement to my ear. I feel it ought to be part of a longer phrase, such as "what nerve he has to *do something so outrageous*". Maybe it's a UK thing.

Comment: Could be regional. Like I said, wasn't aware that "what a nerve" existed until I saw this question. I speak American English.

Comment: "What nerve!" sounds fine.  "What **A** nerve!" sounds like a non-native speaker.  Or, like @Leebo said, a doctor commenting on an impressive physical nerve.

Comment: @istrasci In the US maybe that is the case. In the UK (where I'm from) "What A nerve" is perfectly normal, as I verified today with several friends and the internet. If you don't like it, that's fine. But please don't tell me I sound like a non-native. It is simply not true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

神経 can appear naturally in non-translated conversations. In a sentence like this, it refers to someone's common-sense judgment. どういう神経だ (or どんな神経をしているんだ) may be said after someone said or did something based on an insane judgement. Courage or audacity is not necessarily relevant, so its meaning may be broader than "What a nerve!" in English. But 神経が図太い is an idiom that means "to have strong nerves" or "fearless", so what it actually refers to depends on the phrase.

Comment: So, if someone drunkenly kicks a wall and hurts their foot, would  どんな神経 be appropriate? It seems to fit your definition of "may be said after someone said or did something based on an insane judgement". Just trying to get a feel for how widely applicable it is. Thanks.

Comment: @user3856370 どんな神経だ is unlikely to happen if the kicker was drunken. If a sober person seriously tried to kick through a concrete wall and got hurt, you might say どんな神経をしてるんだ (but not なんて図太い神経なんだ).

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [entries](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/nerve) in Cambridge online, there are these:

- the courage or confidence necessary to do something difficult, unpleasant, or rude:
- the rudeness to do something that you know will upset other people:

In terms of meaning, nerve and 神経 are rather similar. 神経  is used for *daring to do something rude*. どういう神経・どんな神経（してる） is more or less equivalent to *what a nerve*. Rather than 'courage'(勇気) or 'confidence'(自信), it is generally called [厚かましさ](https://jisho.org/word/%E5%8E%9A%E3%81%8B%E3%81%BE%E3%81%97%E3%81%84).

In terms of translation, my impression is that you need to see it as 'what a nerve' in some way even for 'having the nerve'. For example (from the link above),

> She's late for work every day, but she still has the nerve to lecture me about punctuality.
>
> 彼女は毎日遅刻してるのに、自分に時間を守るように言ってくるのはどういう神経をしてるのか (Literally 'what kind of nerve does she have to lecture me about punctuality')

So, in most cases, that sense of 神経 is used in the form of どんな神経 although there are phrases like 神経が太い/図太い神経をしている etc.